# Liquibase. generate-changelog doesn't create script of function creation

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to execute command
`liquibase generate-changelog --changelog-file=baseline.postgresql.sql --diffTypes=functions`
on free version of liquibase (parameters of connection to a database are in `liquibase.properties`). But functions aren't created, the file is empty. Is it supported in the free version. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported in the free version. What generate-changelog does is it creates a changelog file that has a sequence of changesets which describe how to re-create the current state of the database. It is typically used when you want to capture the current state of a database, then apply those changes to any number of databases. This is typically only done when a project has an existing database, but hasn't used Liquibase before.

The documentation has more information here: [Snapshot -generate-changelog](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/snapshot/generate-changelog.html?Highlight=generate%20changelog)

If you still have questions after reviewing that, please reply and include the contents of your liquibase.properties file and any errors you encounter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are no errors. I could generate functions only with trial pro version.